# coldfusion - prevent direct access to files created by user that are meant to be downloaded

Tags: coldfusion

When a user logs into our system, it's possible for the user to create a CSV report.  This report can then be downloaded by the user.  Directory structure is like this:

```
siteroot.com/user/
siteroot.com/user/login/
siteroot.com/user/login/downloads/[file].csv
```

The /login/ directory can only be accessed via a logged in user.  However someone - if they knew the URL - could go directly to the URL of the CSV file and grab the file:

```
siteroot.com/user/login/downloads/myfile.csv
```

Is there any better (simpler) solution than moving them out of the root and then using a cfdirectory / cfheader / cfcontent to pull the CSV file out of a non-IIS directory and give it to the user?

Comment: I suppose if the file name were a long random string, it would be hard for a random person to guess it.

Comment: Why not protect that folder with your web server? Restrict access to those files.

Comment: Protect the folder or remove the files from the web root then store the file paths in the db.. then create a page that allows access to a certain file for x amount of time after they clicked the download CSV link.

Comment: No, there's no better way than the way's you've already described. If you want to be able to authenticate it with coldfusion, it's gotta go through a coldfusion file.

Comment: I ended up creating the files dynamically and storing them outside of webroot.  User is then prompted to save the file using cfheader / cfcontent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put those files in a web accessible folder.

If you're creating a data export that does not need to be kept around, create the file in a temp folder (also not a publicly accessible folder) and use `<cfcontent>` to push the file to the browser, which will present the user with a download dialog. You'll delete the file from the server as part of this process, so you'll run this process every time someone requests the export.

This keeps your server clean and keeps the file behind a login. Here's a gist I created to [stub out this process](https://gist.github.com/iknowkungfoo/1298ef5a65275163c70ad737743c2adc). It uses `<cfspreadsheet>` to accomplish the export. Here's the core of the code:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#config.full_temp_name#" query="config.q" />
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#config.full_temp_name#" name="local.xls" />
<cffile action="delete" file="#config.full_temp_name#" />

<cfif len(arguments.fileName) GT 0>
    <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#arguments.fileName#.#config.extension#" />
<cfelse>
    <cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#config.temp_name#.#config.extension#" />
</cfif>
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(local.xls)#" reset="true" />
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote for that.  Storing outside webroot and using cfheader / cfcontent to prompt the user to download the file is exactly what I did.  The cleanup happens via a scheduled job that runs every x minutes to keep the folder clean.

Comment: The downvote, which did not come from me, was probably inspired by the last paragraph of the question, which makes me surprised that it was marked as the answer.

Comment: There's no point in keeping the files around to be deleted later, especially when you get into high volumes of exports. I developed that CFC for a company that exported tens of thousands of data exports a day.

Comment: I agree with @Dan Bracuk The OP never specified that this was a high volume export scenario, but I would not have downvoted, because your answer, is just providing a strategy for such a scenario, which is covering all bases. The main thrust of your answer is correct. Downloadable files, as a general rule, should be stored above the webroot. For lower volume exports, a scheduled task could be run, once a month, to clear out the directory.